# module has been deprecated and marked for removal

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, java-module

I've added `requires transitive java.activation` to my `module-info.java`, but java-10 is giving me a compiler warning `module-info.java: module java.activation has been deprecated and marked for removal`, despite my having added a dependency on `com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0` (`Automatic-Module-Name: java.activation`) to my Maven `pom.xml`.

I can work around this by adding `@SuppressWarnings("removal")` to my module declaration, but I never like supressing warnings I could be fixing. Is there something else I could be doing to communicate to the compiler my intention to depend on the third party jar and not the built-in/deprecated version of that module?

Much Thanks!

Comment: Just ignore the warning. When you switch to Java 11+ someday, it will just disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

The option `--show-module-resolution` helps observe such behavior. It is only available on `java`, not `javac`, but the JPMS behaves the same in both cases. If you launch the app with that option and *javax.activation-1.2.0.jar* on the module path, you will see this line:

```
root $your-module file:///$your-jar requires java.activation jrt:/java.activation
```

Note that *java.activation* was pulled from `jrt:/java.activation`, not the JAR on the module path. The module system prefers (unfortunately silently) the platform module over one from the module path, which is why your non-deprecated version is not used.

## Solutions

I see three different solutions to your problem.

### Upgrade Module Path

The JAR you're using is a full implementation of the platform module *java.activation* and you can hence use the JAR to replace the module by putting the JAR on the *upgrade module path*:

```
javac
    -d /home/nipa/code/Java-Activation/target/classes
    --upgrade-module-path ~/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:
    -g --release 10 -encoding UTF-8
    `find . -name *.java`
```

The compiler will then use the JAR to replace the platform module of the same name and the deprecation goes away.

As [you discovered yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093463/module-has-been-deprecated-and-marked-for-removal/51094000?noredirect=1#comment89177205_51094000), you can configure the compiler plugin with the command line option:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--upgrade-module-path=${settings.localRepository}/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/${javax.activation.version}/javax.activation-${javax.activation.version}.jar</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Java 11

The JEE modules, like *java.activation*, have been removed from JDK 11, so if you build against 11, the problem goes away.

### Ignore It

You're doing the right thing and it will sort itself out in a few months, so go ahead and ignore the warning. :)

Comment: This did the trick, thanks!

<compilerArg>--upgrade-module-path</compilerArg>
<compilerArg>${settings.localRepository}\com\sun\activation\javax.activation\${javax.activation.version}\javax.activation-${javax.activation.version}.jar</compilerArg>

Comment: Not exactly beautiful, but it works. ;) The JAR is still also on the module path, but that's not a problem.